# Formatting date in Javascript for Sitemap

Tags: javascript, wp-graphql

I am working with a sitemap where the modified date that is being pulled from WP GraphQL is incorrectly formatted which looks like `2021-11-24T17:03:44.597Z`. Looking at Google's recommendations it suggests something like: `2021-11-24T16:02:05+00:00`

Is there an efficient way of converting this to the recommended format?

Comment: Do you have a link to those recommendations? I would guess any ISO 8601 compatible format would pass.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) library and use the following to convert your date:

```
moment(value).utc().format("LLL");
```

Or

```
moment(value).utc().format("M/D/YY");
```

Also, you can check the official documentation, it is very good and flexible for different kinds of date conversions.

As commented @Rawley Fowler you can use [DayJs](https://day.js.org/docs/en/display/format) is recommended by momentJS team and is a lighter and more modern version to do those kind of conversions, to do it with that library you can use:

```
dayjs(value).utc().format('DD/MM/YYYY') // '25/01/2019'
```

Or

```
dayjs(value).utc().format('LLL') // 'January 25, 2019 8:02 PM'
```

This depends on what kind of format you need.

Comment: MomentJS is relatively out of date, I would recommend [DayJS](https://day.js.org/)

Comment: @Rawley Fowler, Thank you, you are right, I just see it that comment about it.

Answer (score 0):

[How to convert yyyy-mm-dd't'hh:mm:ssZ to normal time javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51595561/how-to-convert-yyyy-mm-ddthhmmssz-to-normal-time-javascript)

This should answer your question, just create a `const date = new Date('2021-11-24T17:03:44.597Z')` and then you can `date.getDate()`, `date.getMonth()` etc to format it in a way you need.